# a button for change item properties visible or not

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracleforms

Look at the code i wrote in a button ( when button pressed )

```
set_item_property('TEXT_ITEM17', visible, property_false);
set_item_property('TEXT_ITEM17', visible, property_True);
```

Do I need to put it in if statement ?

Comment: what should this button do? set visible, invisible, switch ?

Comment: Please, specify your requirements.

Comment: yes i need to press the button to show the item and press again to hide it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need this:

```
if get_item_property('TEXT_ITEM17', visible) = 'TRUE' THEN
     set_item_property('TEXT_ITEM17', visible, property_false);    
else
     set_item_property('TEXT_ITEM17', visible, property_true);
end if;
```